Spring @Autowired @Lazy, which bean is lazyily loaded
For Spring 6, With the following code
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private MyRepository myRepository;
}

@Repository
public class MyRepository {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
}

which bean will not be initialized until it is actually needed? Should be properties myRepository inside MyService class? Or the MyService class itself?
